# Why would you leave the brackets in the code without a condition?

Tags: c#, syntax

Why would you leave the open and close brackets in the code without the condition first?
I've seen examples in C# where the code does compile when you have something like this:

```
{
  Console.WriteLine("Hey");
}
```

Is this just bad syntax? or something else?

Comment: It just creates a new [scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/basic-concepts#77-scopes). In this example there is not really a good use for it.

Comment: If you were to, for instance, declare a variable within those braces, it would exist only within those braces.

Comment: You might want to look at the [block statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#123-blocks) and then realise that this *simplifies* the c# language grammar significantly because it doesn't then need to enumerate separate cases for single-line vs multi-line if blocks, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New brackets means new scope.
For example if you want to create variable, which should exists only in specific part of code you can surround it with brackets:

```
{
   var a = 1;
   {
      var b = 2;
      //here 'a' and 'b' exist
   }
   //only 'a' exists
   {
      var b = 2;
      //again 'a' and 'b' exist
   }
   //again only 'a' exists
}
```